# Custom Java Window Title Bar Menu

Tags: java, swing, contextmenu, jinternalframe, custom-titlebar

I'm trying to allow the user to change the title of a window in Java without adding components to the window itself. I'm actually trying this with a `JInternalFrame`, but figure the solution should be similar for a `JFrame`. I simply want to add an additional menu item in the context menu that pops up when right clicking on a window title bar. For example, the *Set title* below:

[image]

This example is on Windows XP, but perhaps there's a way to get the window context menu OS independently perhaps similar to the `SystemTray.getSystemTray()` (but for individual windows *within* an application). From this I would be able to provide my own `ActionListener` to popup a dialog for the user to enter a new title.

Is this a much bigger task than I'm guessing it is? Does anyone have solutions they've used before?

Comment: this funcionaliality comings for Native OS, you have to overode WindowsListener, change DefalutCloseOperation.NOTHING_ON_CLOSE and create JDialog with Custom JMenu and JMenuItes, place this JDialog to the left-top windows container on Window' Close event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: I don't think this is easy. I'm not 100% sure if it is possible.

First, JFrame and JInternalFrame are actually quite different. JFrame is a top level component whose title bar and such are typically provided by the OS. JInternalFrame's entire content (including title bar) is provided by the Swing LAF.

For a JInternalFrame, the context menu is provided by the LAF, not JInternalFrame itself. You would have to do something with the UIComponent in order to change the context menu. I think you would likely have to provide a custom UI component in order to do this, which is ugly and typically breaks across different LAFs or works but looks terrible at best. See [BasicInternalFrameTitlePane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.html), the `createSystemMenu` method.

Comment: +1 That's basically what I meant with 'digging too deep'. Thanks for elaborating :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without digging way too deep into Swing's internal UI system and I wouldn't even consider doing this. Why don't you use the inbuilt `JMenuBar` of `JInternalFrame`?

```
myInternalFrame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
```